# First recorded use of oxymel to treat wounds

Tags: medicine, ancient

What is the first recorded use of a mixure of honey and vinegar to treat wounds?
[Cato the Elder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymel) indicates it was used during Roman times, but it's unclear if this was as a tonic or if it was used to clean wounds